# Update + Select в одном запросе Для одной таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть одна таблица с 2 полями login и type.
Как можно в одном запросе получить type у пользователя A и обновить type у пользователя Б

Comment: Пробовал вот так UPDATE `users`
SET `type` = (
    SELECT `type`
    FROM `users`
    WHERE `login` = 'user1'

)
WHERE `login` = 'user2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно добавить еще один уровень

```
UPDATE users 
  SET type = (
      SELECT type FROM (
           select * from users
           ) t 
        WHERE login = 'user1' 
      ) 
   WHERE login = 'user2'
```

---

для нескольких полей

```
UPDATE users t1,
  (
  SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT f1,f2
        FROM users       
        WHERE login = 'user1'
    ) t2
SET t1.f1 = t2.f1, t1,f2 = t2.f2
WHERE login = 'user2'
```

Comment: как правильно необходимо поступать, если необходимо обновить несколько полей (type1, type2, type3) не писать же под каждый type такие вложенные селекты?

Comment: вложенные селекты нужны потому что mysql не позволяет одну и туже таблицу использовать для изменений и для поиска. поэтому м как бы создаем временную таблицу, и по ее значениям обновляем основную

Comment: @IceRD я обновил ответ